# How to add quick launch toolbar in Windows 10 1909 - older instructions DO NOT WORK

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1909, quicklaunch

I upgraded to Windows 10 1909, and I'd like my quicklauch toolbar back.

All the instructions I'm seeing for Windows 10 say to add this directory
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch
in the new toolbar window, and then press select folder.

These instruction create a document toolbar, and I can't drag all the way to the left.

The part in the red box below is what's being added using the above instructions, and it comes complete with three recent documents in it.  It's supposed to be an application quicklaunch.  This is a clean install of Windows 10 1909 (two days ago), so there is nothing left over that is causing this.

[image]
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't know what "the first icon" is.

Comment: There is nothing special about the quick launch folder.  It is just a folder with some shortcuts in it.  Make any folder you want.  Copy the shortcuts into it you want for "Quicklaunch".  Add that toolbar.. or go into the "Documents" folder I see in your screen shot and copy shortcuts there.  Is there something I am not understanding?

Comment: Also.. what I mean by "the first Icon".. if you were to disable the text (removing `Documents`) the explorer would take the first icon from that folder and display that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work.  This does not match any documentation I have seen.

1. Unlock the taskbar. (Right click on the task bar, uncheck item).
2. Open a File Explorer window and put in this address:
   %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch
3. Navigate up one directory, so the "Quick Launch" folder is listed in the contents.
4. Select the path at the top of the window, and press Ctrl-C. Close the window. On my computer it is C:\Users(my username)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
5. Right click on the task bar, Toolbars -> New Toolbar...
6. Select the directory at the top so it's highlighted, and press Ctrl-V. Press Enter.
7. Select (highlight) the "Quick Launch" directory.
8. Press select folder at the bottom right of the Window
9. The quick launch toolbar is now on the right side of your taskbar.
10. You can drag it to the left.
11. Right click on the vertical parallel bars just to the left of quick launch item.
12. Uncheck show text.  Repeat, and uncheck show title.
13. Re-lock the taskbar.

It may be possible to skip step 3, and then for 6/7, just press Ctrl-V. I'm posting exactly what I did. (And I'm not rebuilding my quick launch bar to test that.)  If you get a documents toolbar, go back and follow the instructions exactly.

Comment: How is this different than the online instructions you claimed didn't work?

Comment: The instructions in my question create a Document launch bar, which is wrong.  I did it several times.  It also contains a list of documents, pre-loaded.  I thought this was very odd. Using the method in my  answer gives you an empty Quick launch folder, and it's called "Quick Lauch" on the task bar (before I removed the text).

Answer (score 0):

I tested to add a quick launch toolbar to taskbar on my Windows 10 1909 device, and available to drag it by click it at first then appear an arrow icon to drag.

I would recommend to make sure you have unlocked task bar, or restarted Windows explorer through Task manager. Restart PC some times might be helpful to resolve those strange issue.

Comment: So you were able to get the quicklaunch to work, and add apps to it? (You just drag an icon from the desktop and hold it over the toolbar arrows).  I have already done what you suggested, and I had the taskbar unlocked.

Comment: I noticed you have resolved it by yourself. Good news to hear that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.